# Lookup Placeholder's Label field via the Expression window in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am hoping there is a way to lookup the Label field of a Placeholder Property via the Expression window. This would help me avoid hard-coding the Lookup value in my expression.

[image]

Comment: Jamie I am looking for the same to access the Label property of a ReportItem. Have you been successful?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe that this is possible. However, you could create a variable and then use the value of the variable in your expression if you wish to avoid hard-coding a value in your expression. Variables can be created by opening Report Properties under Report in the toolbar.